# When I use pycharm, split function makes a error like this pic

Tags: split, pycharm

When I use pycharm and split it doesn't work.(only at pycharm)
I don't know how to fix this.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Regression in 2022.1.1 PyCharm, see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-54238/STDIN-is-lost-for-a-second-input-call

Update to [2022.1.2 RC (release candidate)](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/articles/PY-A-23004355) where the problem is resolved.